# Is there a way possible to not just switch on the windows Instance in GCP but also log in to a specific user account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have auto scheduled my instance timings in Windows Server over GCP using the `cloud functions`. Now I all I want to do is that during the switchinch on of the instance, It should also log in to a specific user account - as I have setup some startup scripts for different users. Does anyone know or have tried some way to perform this?

My end goal is whenever my instance is switched on it should not just switch on but log into the windows instance with a specified user which happens through RDP manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "log in to a specific account". You will either need to implement the RDP protocol, WSMAN or Powershell. This would be a huge task for Cloud Functions. You could install the Microsoft OpenSSH server and then using SSH connect to the Windows system and rexec commands. Rethink your design. It would be far easier to create a REST server running on Windows that you call to execute commands.

Comment: @JognHanley Thanks for your insights. When I say "log in to a specific account" I mean log in to windows machine from a specific user. The reason for going with the User Login is that I need to perform some UI Automations like going to a browser and clicking a button which I am doing using UIPath. I don't think SSH is good option when it comes to running the commands that involve UI interactions (opening browsers clicking buttons etc)

Comment: Your goal is UI interaction with Window Server from Cloud Functions? You are trying to build a skyscraper when only a matchbox is required. Nowhere in your question did you mention UI interaction. You will need to implement the RDP protocol to scrape the GUI remotely.

Comment: Not actually performing the UI Interaction with cloud functions, just something that RDPs into the instance so that the script can start running in the system. Also, for the RDP protocol, the flow is like this: 1. Auto Instance Switch On -> RDP or Windows Login and then from there a startup script takes care of all the UI interactions. My very specific problem is since, currently I RDP manually, I need to automate it in such a way that when the instance is turned on RDP takes place automatically as well So that there's no manual human intervention.

Comment: OK, go implement the RDP protocol in Cloud Functions.

Comment: I see. Thanks can you point me to any resources for the same? That will be really helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226278/discussion-between-shivam-sahil-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Chat is not necessary. You need to do your own research. Once you have a programming question that you need help with create a question.